# How do I transfer data used to create a shape from a C++ program into excel using a csv file?

Tags: excel, visual-c++, export-to-csv

This is my C++ code so far:

The program asks the user to enter their group name. If the name is c4, the program then asks for x and y coordinates, a radius for the circle in the shape, and a spacing between each point along the lines. The program will then calculate points and angles for the shape. The shape should be a circle with three lines coming from the edge of the circle at 22.5, 45 and 67.5 degrees.

```
/ computinggroup.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
        //

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> //necessary for cout and endl
#include <cmath> //necessary for mathematic calculations
#include <string> //necessary for declaration of letters
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//group project
//Group c4
//date: 22/03/2013

{
string c; //declaration of letter
int d = 0; //inisialise group name elements
int i, b;
double pi = 3.141592654; //define pi for trig calculations
double r, a = 0;
double x, x1 = 0;
double y, y1 = 0;
double xa, xb, ya, yb = 0;
double increment, spacing, numofpoints;
double AngleB;
double AngleV;
double AngleTheta1;
double AngleTheta2;

/****************************************************************************
* SECTION 1 - Group name is entered by user, the programme continues if it is
* the correct name, if not a message displays and the programme stops
*****************************************************************************/

cout << "Enter letter from group name: ";
cin >> c;
cout << "Enter number from group name: ";
cin >> d;
if (c == "C", d == 4)
{ 
cout << "Group " << c << d;
cout << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "Incorrect group name entered, the programme cannot continue. Press any key to exit";
cin >> d;
return 0;
}

/****************************************************************************
* SECTION 2 - User enters values for centre point of the circle 
* and radius, the programme creates x and y coordinate points for 360 points
* around a circle
*****************************************************************************/

cout << "Enter x coordinate for the centre of the circle: ";
cin >> x1;
cout << "Enter y coordinate for the centre of the circle: ";
cin >> y1;
cout << "Enter radius of the circle: ";
cin >> r;
cout << "Enter spacing required between each point along the lines: ";
cin >> spacing;
numofpoints = (2 * pi * r)/spacing;
increment = 360/numofpoints;
for (i = 0; i < 360 ; i+=increment) //loop the calculation for values of x for i = 0 to 360 in intervals of 'increment'
{
x = x1 + (r * cos((i * pi)/180));
cout << "(" << x << ","; 
y = y1 + (r * sin((i * pi)/180));
cout << y << ")";
cout << endl;
AngleB = acos(x/pow((pow(x, 2))+(pow(y, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(x, 2))+(pow(y, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(x, 2))+(pow(y, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(asin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(x, 2))+(pow(y, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
}
/****************************************************************************
* SECTION 3 - start and end coordinates for each of the 3 lines 
* The naming is as follows: example, 'xa'; 'x' means the x coordinate, 
* 'a' means start point as oppossed to 'b' for end point
*****************************************************************************/
cout << endl;
cout << "Coordinates of three lines: ";
cout << endl;
//the first line is at 22.5 deg, trigonometry is used to create the function
{
double a = 22.5;
xa = x1 + (r * cos((a * pi)/180));
ya = y1 + (r * sin((a * pi)/180));
AngleB = acos(xa/pow((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xa*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
xb = x1 + (2 * r + (r * cos((a * pi)/180)));
yb = y1 + (2 * r + (r * sin((a * pi)/180)));
AngleB = acos(xb/pow((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xb*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
cout << "Line at " << a << " degrees = (" << xa << ", " << ya << ") to (" << xb << ", " << yb << ")";
cout << endl;
}
//the second line is at 45 deg
{
double a = 45;
xa = x1 + (r * cos((a * pi)/180));
ya = y1 + (r * sin((a * pi)/180));
AngleB = acos(xa/pow((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xa*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
xb = x1 + (2 * r + (r * cos((a * pi)/180)));
yb = y1 + (2 * r + (r * sin((a * pi)/180)));
AngleB = acos(xb/pow((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xb*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
cout << "Line at " << a << " degrees = (" << xa << ", " << ya << ") to (" << xb << ", " << yb << ")";
cout << endl;
}
//the third line is at 67.5 deg
{
double a = 67.5;
xa = x1 + (r * cos((a * pi)/180));
ya = y1 + (r * sin((a * pi)/180));
AngleB = acos(xa/pow((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xa*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xa, 2))+(pow(ya, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
xb = x1 + (2 * r + (r * cos((a * pi)/180)));
yb = y1 + (2 * r + (r * sin((a * pi)/180)));
AngleB = acos(xb/pow((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2)), 0.5))*(180/pi);
cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleV = acos(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))+(10000)-(4225))/(200*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/pi);
cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta1 = AngleB - AngleV;
cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta1<<" Degrees"<<endl;
AngleTheta2 =(xb*sin(pow(((sin(AngleV*pi/180))*(pow(((pow(xb, 2))+(pow(yb, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/pi);
cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta2<<" Degrees"<<endl;
cout << "Line at " << a << " degrees = (" << xa << ", " << ya << ") to (" << xb << ", " << yb << ")";
cout << endl;
}
cout << "Press any key to exit ... "; //the user has the option to exit
cin >> b;
return 0;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know c++, but doesn't the `math` library contain a `pi` function, so you don't need to define a variable. Beyond that, I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Rory. You have certainly put a lot of work into your program.  What's not clear, though, is what your specific question is (as Doug Glancy notes). Try to improve the question by honing in on the key obstacles that are holding you back at this stage of your coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand C++ at all so I wouldn't be able to tell you how to get it to actually write the file.

If you don't really want to open a file explicitly, you might be able to use stdout?

so you can run your program from the command line and pipe the result to a file.

eg: `mymathapp.exe > result.csv`

The CSV format isn't difficult to understand.

Every line represents a row, and the column data is just a delimited list on that line. (you can use a comma, or tab etc). String values are typically `"Quoted"` but it's not usually a requirement (excel, and other apps are generally fairly forgiving).

example of how you might output a line to stdout.

`fprintf(stdout, "%d, %d, %d, %d\n", val1, val2, val3, val4);`